# PHP foreach loop without the as?

Tags: php, arrays, json, foreach, feed

I'm retrieving data from a json feed like this:

```
{
  'data': {

   'stuffs': [
     {
       'cats': '12',
       'dogs': '53',
       'bananas': '8',
     },
     {
       'cats': '42',
       'dogs': '49',
       'bananas': '18',

     },
     {
       'cats': '14',
       'dogs': '900',
       'bananas': '2',
     }]

  }
}
```

And grabbing the data with a function like this:

```
function getData($url){

     $json = file_get_contents($url);                                      
     $json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);

       foreach ($url['data']['stuffs'] as $benum){

         $cats = $benum['cats'];
         $dogs = $benum['dogs'];
         $bananas = $benum['bananas'];

       }



    $myarray = array(

    "cat" => $cats,
    "dog" => $dogs,
    "banana" => $bananas,

    );

  return $myarray;

}
```

I want to set up a foreach loop something like this:

```
   foreach ($myarray as $data){

   echo $data['cat'];
   echo $data['dog'];
   echo $data['banana'];

   }
```

And have it return something like this :

```
 12
 53
 8

 42
 49
 18

 14
 900
 2
```

But foreach($myarray as $data) is not working.

The problem is that it only returns 1 character from each key in the array which seems to be random.

Is there something that I could do that would be like not having "as" in the foreach at all?

Like:

```
  foreach($myarray){

      // the goods    

  }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The "as" operator in foreach acts as a recursive resource. BTW you can use `array_keys` and do any iteraction, recursive or not based on your business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getData($url){

     $myarray = array();

     $json = file_get_contents($url);                                      
     $json_output = json_decode($json, TRUE);

       foreach ($url['data']['stuffs'] as $benum){

         $cats = $benum['cats'];
         $dogs = $benum['dogs'];
         $bananas = $benum['bananas'];

         $myarray[] = array(

            "cat" => $cats,
           "dog" => $dogs,
            "banana" => $bananas,

            );

       }

}

 foreach ($myarray as $data){

   echo $data['cat'];
   echo $data['dog'];
   echo $data['banana'];

   }
```

You should get the result in the way you want. You will always need the "as" with foreach.

Comment: I was missing those brackets (" $myarray[] = array... "), the problem is halfway solved, but it only shows one result. I'll check back once I get it fixed.

Comment: I fixed it by completely commenting out the array I made and just looping through the json feed. Which was what I was doing before. Thanks anyway. +1

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use foreach you still have to use the as

```
foreach ($myarray as $val){
    echo $val;
}
```

For the test array:

```
$myarray = array(
    "cat" => '12',
    "dog" => '5',
    "banana" => '7'
);
```

This will output

```
12
5
7
```